# What does the function ttyn(3) return?

Tags: tty, c

The man page is here: http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/3/ttyn

This example:

```
if (ttyn(0) = 'x'){
...
}
```

The man page says "*x is returned if the indicated file does not correspond to  a
     typewriter.*"

The indicated file would be argument 0, so the standardinput, right?

And what is a typewriter? My keyboard?

**What are you checking with this line?**

```
if (ttyn(0) = 'x')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At that point in time, a typewriter (or teletype, or tty) was an RS-232 terminal connected to the computer via a serial port. The device entries in `/dev` corresponding to these ports were named `/dev/tty0`, `/dev/tty1`, `/dev/ttya`, etc. Each of those files was a *character special* file, as opposed to an ordinary file.

When a terminal was detected by the system, typically by being turned on or connected through a modem, the `init` process opened the device on file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 in a new process, and those file descriptors persisted through the login process, a user's shell, and any processes forked from the shell.

As you said in your question, file descriptor 0 is also called *standard input*.

The `ttyn` function calls `fstat` on its argument, which returns some info about the file such as its inode number, permissions, etc. `ttyn` then reads through `/dev`, looking at each file that starts with `"tty"`, to see which one has the same inode number as `ttyn`'s argument. When it finds a match, it returns the 4th character of the filename, which would be `'0'`, `'1'`, `'a'`, etc. If no matches are found, it returns `'x'`.

There were generally a console and a few 8-port serial interfaces on a PDP-11. so there was no `ttyx`. And you could name devices in `/dev` anything you wanted. So it was easy to avoid `/dev/ttyx` being an actual device.

Commands like `goto` could use `ttyn(0) != 'x'` to determine whether the user was actually typing the command on a terminal.

---

[Here](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/etc/ttys) is the default config file, `/etc/ttys`, used by `init` in V6. The console was `tty8`.

In V7 Unix, the functionality of [ttyn](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/s3/ttyn.s) was replaced by [ttyname](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/libc/gen/ttyname.c), which could accommodate longer device names, and [isatty](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/libc/gen/isatty.c), which returned true if the fle descriptor was a terminal device. The [goto](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/s1/goto.c) command was not present in V7.

Comment: you said "... to determine whether the user was actually typing the command on a terminal." 

But why would you want to determine that? Is there any problem if the user typed it on anything else?

Comment: @Kevin Not all file operations work the same on ordinary files and terminal devices. In particular, a terminal device doesn't have a read/write pointer that can be moved backwards. The `goto` command works by seeking back to the beginning of its standard input and reading until it finds a certain line. That works fine if the standard input is a shell script, but won't work very well if the standard input is a terminal. It would just wait for the user to type a line like `: target`. So `goto` checks if standard input is a terminal, and refuses to continue if that's the case.

Comment: Now everything is clear :) Thank you so much Mark! Have a nice day :)

Comment: thanks. I was playing with the V6 program `goto.c` and trying to port it to modern sh (brilliant idea, amirite?).

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this library call before; I'm used to the more familiar `ttyname`.  The webpage doesn't give a return value, but based on what the text says, it would give the last `char` value in the string returned by `ttynam(3)`.  So if stdin (fd0) was connected to "/dev/tty2", then the return value would be the char `2`.  And in C, you would be able to check it with:

```
if (ttyn(0) == '2') { ... }
```

Granted the documentation is not clear.  And it is using bad terminology; instead of "typewriter", it should be using "teletype" or "terminal", which are the accepted terms.  Remember that stdin can be different from stdout;  it is perfectly possible to do run `cat </dev/tty1 > /dev/tty2`, assuming you have the permissions for it.

Comment: There is precedent for "typewriter" though; historically `strerror(ENOTTY)` would return `"Not a typewriter"`.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_a_typewriter